# Unable to Reinstall Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, kernel, 15.10

I am running 15.10 on a custom build.  I recently upgraded from 15.04, which, for reasons I do not understand, broke MySql.  I ran a fix to Upstart, which fixed MySql temporarily, but left me completely unable to log in at all upon reboot.  After some research and mild panic I decided to just reinstall over the previous installation, because that allegedly saves all data etc.  Pop in install disk, it found the previous installation, but I backed out of the install before letting it get started because I had to run an errand.  I never got past the time zone bit.  Upon returning I boot to the USB again, and now it's no longer finding the previous install.  It is saying that there are no OS installed.  However, when I boot without the install stick I still go back to my normal Ubuntu login.  When I boot to GRUB I still have all of my GRUB options.  However, when I try to boot into recovery mode for GRUB I'm now getting an error after a time that says

No init found.  Try passing init= bootarg

I then get a BusyBox shell.  I have no shell skills whatsoever so this is where I panic.  I really, really, desperately need to fix this.  I can't lose everything I have on this machine.  It would probably cost me my job.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  But please, I may need you to explain it like I'm five at this point as the panic mode is fully engaged.

Edit: When booting from a live CD my drives and partitions all show in GParted and all are healthy

Comment: Have you tried to boot in the Ubuntu Live CD/USB and used GParted to see if it detects your current Ubuntu partition?

Comment: Stop trying to install/reinstall and backup your files first.

Comment: I've backed up what I can. There are permission issues with accessing them later but that's another problem for another day

Answer (score 0):

You should try to run `boot repair`, that's for the booting part. As far as for the login concerns, you should try to login as root if you know the root password. Else, if you cannot login at all, you should remove your hard drive and use it in another computer as an external hard drive (there're tools to do that). As for the future, I recommend you use [docker](http://docker.com) or [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) holding a stable version of mysql, php or whatever you use.

Comment: Grub repair has been run successfully to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check Your boot Option  from BIOS menu.
If it is UEFI change it to LEGACY 
And try to reinstall operating system